# How to create a toolbar with a real button inside?

Tags: android, material-design, android-toolbar

I want to create a toolbar with a button like in the Google calendar app:
[image]
I want my toolbar to have the x on the left and the Save button on the right.

I don't need/want any title or the chevron symbol (which in case of the Google calendar simply comes from the BottomSheet)

Answer (score 0):

```
You can add button in the toolbar as  follows:

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_close_black_24dp">

    <Button
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Save"
        android:layout_gravity="end" />
</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```